# Query nodes above given record in tree

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table

```
               Table "public.menu_items"
   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | integer |           | not null | 
 name        | text    |           |          | 
 parent_id   | integer |           |          | 
 position    | integer |           |          | 
 is_category | boolean |           |          |
```

And I have this tree of records

```
Lesson1 (id: 1, parent_id: null, position: 1, is_category: false)
Category2 (id: 2, parent_id: null, position: 2, is_category: true)
|_ Lesson2.1 (id: 5, parent_id: 2, position: 1, is_category: false)
|_ Category2.2 (id: 6, parent_id: 2, position: 2, is_category: true)
   |_ Lesson2.2.1 (id: 8, parent_id: 6, position: 1, is_category: false)
   |_ Lesson2.2.2 (id: 9, parent_id: 6, position: 2, is_category: false)
   |_ Lesson2.2.3 (id: 10, parent_id: 6, position: 3, is_category: false)
   |_ Lesson2.2.4 (id: 11, parent_id: 6, position: 4, is_category: false)
|_ (Lesson2.3 (id: 7, parent_id: 2, position: 3, is_category: false)
Lesson3 (id: 3, parent_id: null, position: 3, is_category: false)
Category4 (id: 4, parent_id: null, position: 4, is_category: true)
```

I know `id` and `position` of record for example id = 10, position = 3. (Lesson2.2.3)

And I need to query All lessons(is_category = false) above given record in tree. In our case

```
Lesson1 (id: 1, parent_id: null, position: 1, is_category: false)
Lesson2.1 (id: 5, parent_id: 2, position: 1, is_category: false)
Lesson2.2.1 (id: 8, parent_id: 6, position: 1, is_category: false)
Lesson2.2.2 (id: 9, parent_id: 6, position: 2, is_category: false)
```

I probably need to use `WITH RECURSIVE` for this. How to write such a query?

**UPDATE**
Now my query looks like this, but it fetches only ancestors, I probably need nested `WITH RECURSIVE` to fetch children of each ancestor.

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM menu_items
   WHERE parent_id =
       (SELECT parent_id
        FROM menu_items
        WHERE id = 10)
     AND POSITION < 3
   UNION SELECT x.*
   FROM menu_items x
   JOIN r ON x.id = r.parent_id
   OR (x.parent_id IS NULL
       AND r.parent_id IS NULL
       AND x.position <
         (SELECT POSITION
          FROM menu_items
          WHERE id = r.id)))
SELECT *
FROM r;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lau How to query lessons above given record in a tree? I don't know how to do it `WITH RECURSIVE`.

Comment: I believe positition of Lesson2.2.4 should be 4? Do you want all lessons or only the four you mentioned (if so why only these?)

Comment: I don't really understand the tree. In your example the Lesson1 has the id = 1. But all its children have a parent_id = 2. This will not work...

Comment: @S-Man Lesson1 does not have any children, this is children of Category2.

Comment: @S-Man Yes, `position` should be 4. It was a typo.

Comment: I did not try the query provided by @S-Man but it is probably all good. Note that the initial `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` is your start condition, that you can change freely (e.g. `WHERE id = 10` to start recursion from Lesson 2.2.3). The `JOIN` at the bottom defines the direction you are browsing the tree. `ON l.parent_id = rl.id` is from the root to the leaves, `l.id = rl.parent_id` would then be from leaves up to the root. You do not need to browse the entire table, even though as a beginner, you should give it a try to understand the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I am not quiet sure if I got your use case completely (see comments under the question). But in general this is a solution. Maybe you should calibrate some little things...

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=eb9620ab984f7b5ad083a35c47c3eb44)

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec_lessons AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        position,
        name,
        parent_id,
        position::text as path,
        is_category
    FROM
        lessons
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        l.id,
        l.position,
        l.name,
        l.parent_id,
        rl.path || '.' || l.position,
        l.is_category
    FROM
        lessons l
    JOIN rec_lessons rl ON l.parent_id = rl.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM rec_lessons
WHERE is_category = false
```

A recursive CTE always consists of two parts divided by the `UNION` clause. The first query is the starting point, the second one the recursion part.

At the start we need to find all rows that may be your tree roots. I assumed that this would be all with no parent.

For the recursion we query all rows from the original table which have as parent_id the id of the previous turn. That's what the join does. So at start all roots have the `ids` `(1,2,3,4)`. In the first recursion we find all rows where the `parent_ids` are one of `(1,2,3,4)`. That give us the rows with the `ids` `(5,6,7)`. These rows are united to the start result with `UNION ALL`. The next step is to find all rows with `parent_ids` are one of `(5,6,7)` and so on.

I added the path which can describe the tree. This is expanded in every turn.

Finally (outside the `WITH` clause) I filter all non-categories.

Comment: You misunderstand me, a little. I have a lesson id. And I need to fetch all previous lessons in a tree except itself. For id = 10 it would be rows with id (9,8,5,1); For id = 3 it would be rows with id (11,10,9,8,5,1); For id = 5 it would be row with id = 1. Please let me know if it is clear, thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. But this is really a hard problem because you need two nested recursions. One for searching up from starting point and then for all previous siblings search down. I wouldn't recommend to do this with plain SQL.

Comment: There is the "ltree" extension which would help. It stores the tree in a path structure - very similar to what I created in my example. And if you stored these paths it would be very simple to query your result. You just need to ask SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE path < ${path from start point}